# How to convert string to number in python?

Tags: python, string, integer, numbers, converters

I have list of numbers as str

```py
li = ['1', '4', '8.6']
```

if I use `int` to convert the result is `[1, 4, 8]`.
If I use `float` to convert the result is `[1.0, 4.0, 8.6]`

I want to convert them to `[1, 4, 8.6]`

I've tried this:

```py
li = [1, 4, 8.6]
intli = list(map(lambda x: int(x),li))
floatli = list(map(lambda x: float(x),li))
print(intli)
print(floatli)

>> [1, 4, 8]
>> [1.0, 4.0, 8.6]
```

Comment: do you plan to support negative numbers as well? as in `['-5', '-8.3']`

Comment: yes it should accept negative numbers aswell

Answer (score 8):

Convert the items to a integer if `isdigit()` returns `True`, else to a float. This can be done by a list generator:

```
li = ['1', '4', '8.6']
lst = [int(x) if x.isdigit() else float(x) for x in li]
print(lst)
```

To check if it actually worked, you can check for the types using another list generator:

```
types = [type(i) for i in lst]
print(types)
```

Comment: voting up because It's a good answer but if there is a negative integer then it will convert to a negative float.

Comment: unfortunately, `isdigit` matches much more than just `0..9`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` to convert an string to a literal:

```py
from ast import literal_eval

li = ['1', '4', '8.6']
numbers = list(map(literal_eval, li))
```

As @Muhammad Akhlaq Mahar noted in his comment, `str.isidigit` does not return `True` for negative integers:

```py
>>> '-3'.isdigit()
False
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> spam = ['1', '4', '8.6']
>>> [literal_eval(item) for item in spam]
[1, 4, 8.6]
```

Word of caution - there are values which return True with str.isdigit() but not convertible to int or float and in case of literal_eval will raise SyntaxError.

```
>>> '1²'.isdigit()
True
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need a small utility function:

```
def to_float_or_int(s):
    n = float(s)
    return int(n) if n.is_integer() else n
```

Then,

```
result = [to_float_or_int(s) for s in li]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `map` each element using `loads` from `json`:

```
from json import loads
li = ['1', '4', '8.6']
li = [*map(loads,li)]
print(li)

# [1, 4, 8.6]
```

Or using `eval()`:

```
print(li:=[*map(eval,['1','4','8.6','-1','-2.3'])])

# [1, 4, 8.6, -1, -2.3]
```

Notes:

> Using `json.loads()` or `ast.literal_eval` is safer than `eval()` when
> the string to be evaluated comes from an unknown source